# How to SELECT multiple values from a row and join it as a single column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi this is my database structure and data, I want to get the following output as shown in the image below.

I have a section in the table where the foodtypes allow multiple value so i have made 2 tables, 1 table for the values(**dd_foods**) and 1 more for the section ID(**restaurant_food**). now i want to select those multiple row id values from **restaurant_food.foodtype** but as the name from **dd_foods**. How do i do that?

[image: database structure]

*I'm not sure how to explain it here so i made an image sorry if it's confusing.*

Comment: Use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, GROUP_CONCAT(dd.foodtypes)
FROM restaurants r 
INNER JOIN restaurants_food rf on rf.restaurants_id = r.id 
INNER JOIN dd_foods dd on dd.id = rf.food_id
GROUP BY r.id, r.name
```

Comment: To my way of thinking, and to a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is the solution - especially so when application-level code is available

Answer (score 1):

Just use something like...

```
SELECT r.*
     , f.* 
  FROM restaurants r 
  JOIN restaurant_foodtype rf 
    ON rf.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id 
  JOIN foodtypes f 
    ON f.foodtype_id = rf.foodtype_id;
```

...and handle everything else in your application level code

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, concat(restaurant, "-", foodtype) as restaurant_info
from(
select r.id as id, CONCAT(r.id, "-" ,r.name, "-") as restaurant, group_concat(ddf.foodtypes  separator ',') as foodtype
from restaurants as r
inner join restaurant_food as rf on rf.restaurants_id = r.id
inner join dd_foods as ddf on ddf.id = rf.food_id
)
```